# Can deep successor representations be used with the A3C algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, papers, a3c

[Deep Successor Representations(DSR)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02396) has given better performance in tasks like navigation, when compared to normal model-free RL tasks. Basically, DSR is a hybrid of model-free RL and model-based RL. But the original work has only used value-based functions deep RL methods like DQN.

Can deep successor representations be used with the A3C algorithm?